# Can I Use Microsoft Graph to Convert MSWord Documents to Other Formats?

Tags: ms-office, microsoft-graph-api

I want to take a .DOC or .DOCX file and convert it to another file format; e.g. PDF or HTML, etc. *I don't have MS Word loaded on the local machine nor do I have an Office 365 account.*

Will Microsoft Graph provide a way to do this programmatically, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks in advance for any insight or ideas!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Microsoft Graph (https://graph.microsoft.io/) can't be used to convert your .DOC or .DOCX files into another format, especially if you don't have MS Word or Office365. Microsoft Graph is basically 'just' an interface to access your data/objects stored in your Office365 tennant.

Without MS Word your only option (besides third party tooling) to convert would be to use Office Open XML, but even so that wouldn't suit your need as .DOC files are not based on the open XML standard. Also rendering to PDF is also not part of the Office Open XML specifications so you need to find another service to do that if you don't want MS Word to do that for you.

So in short, to answer your question ... no you can't use Microsoft Graph to convert MSWord documents to other formats.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy and direct answer. Let's say the criteria changed and I now have access to Office365. Would your answer change?

Comment: These days, Microsoft Graph can be used to convert doc/docx to PDF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content-format?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in various ways in Office365/Graph:

1. Do a http GET to the drives API in MS Graph. Example:

GET /drive/items/{item-id}/content?format={format}

This also works for files in SharePoint.

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get_content_format

2. Via the Convert File action in Microsoft Flow. See John Liu's blog on this.

Answer (score 0):

[Essential DocIO](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/docio) is an option to consider. The library can convert from Doc and Docx to PDF and doesn't rely on Microsoft Office.

The entire product is available for free with no limitations through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million US$ in revenue per year).

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Comment: Essential DocIO is new to me. How does it compare to something like Aspose?

Comment: @surfbored Essential DocIO is similar to Aspose Words. You should be able to achieve similar  functionality using either library.

Answer (score 0):

Today the Microsoft Graph doesn't provide this functionality, but it's a reasonable request.  You might want to raise it over at uservoice [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't heard of uservoice before. It's nice to learn something new as a bonus.